# SQL Query cycle

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that takes me: Extensão data 
My Query:

```
DECLARE @extensaoX VARCHAR(50)

SELECT  @extensaoX = RIGHT(Extensão,3) FROM [BD_Teste2].[dbo].[Users] WHERE Extensão <>'' AND ISNUMERIC([Extensão]) = 1

SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), CAST(@extensaoX AS BIGINT))
```

Result:

```
(No column name)

0x000000014BBF0767
```

My problem (difficulty), i need to convert all fields, but i dont know how..
Some cycle to run the table and convert the data?

```
Extensão   (No column name)

123        0x000000014BBF0767 

213        ?????????????

345        ?????????????
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CAST(RIGHT(Extensão,3) AS BIGINT) as Extensão,
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), CAST(RIGHT(Extensão,3) AS BIGINT))
FROM [BD_Teste2].[dbo].[Users]
WHERE Extensão <>''
  AND ISNUMERIC([Extensão]) = 1
```

maybe you need this?

```
SELECT
    CAST(RIGHT(Extensão,3) AS BIGINT) as Extensão,
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), CAST(RIGHT(Extensão,3) AS BIGINT))
FROM [BD_Teste2].[dbo].[Users]
WHERE Extensão  NOT NULL
  AND ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(Extensão,3)) = 1
```

Comment: The original select only gets one row (which it should otherwise the assignment would fail) so yours will too, because the where conditions are the same. So this will not do `Some cycle to run the table` so to speak.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, I think you must check your assumptions before posting.

Comment: Sorry I did not mean insult or anything, but your `WHERE` is identical to the one used in OP where am I assuming something wrong?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste You assumption `which it should otherwise the assignment would fail` is wrong. If you will check it, you would got answer for your second question.

Comment: True, I was a bit fast on the typing, after I saw that assignment to a scalar variable I assumed a little too much, sorry about that and thanks for your clarification :-)

Comment: The indicated query shows only 3 results. 
If i run the following query, i have 166 lines total: Extensão

select right(Extensão,3) FROM [SP_TESTE_Content].[dbo].[Users]  where Extensão <>''

Extensão

636
 
205
 
205

301

...

Comment: @JavaLL It is filtered by predicate which states that the `Extensão` is not empty and is numeric. Can you provide example data that was skipped by query.

Comment: SELECT [Extensão] FROM [BD_Teste2].[dbo].[Users]

Extensão

(44) 413
NULL
292 411 123 - 151
NULL
(44) 213
NULL
NULL
(44) 451
(40) 350

Comment: @JavaLL Con you separate the values by comma?

Comment: ok ;) 

SELECT [Extensão] FROM [BD_Teste2].[dbo].[Users]

Extensão:

(44) 413,
NULL,
292 411 123 - 151,
NULL,
(44) 213,
NULL,
NULL,
(44) 451,
(40) 350,

Comment: Then what you want? All provided values doesn't meet the WHERE predicate. Non of them is numeric and also, notice that empty (<>'') isn't null.

Comment: I want all of my results list  ( select right(Extensão,3) FROM [SP_TESTE_Content].[dbo].[Users]  where Extensão <>''  )
(166 row(s) affected)

Extensão:
123,
213,
455,

But converted as indicated in the query (SELECT
    CAST(RIGHT(Extensão,3) AS BIGINT) as Extensão,
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), CAST(RIGHT(Extensão,3) AS BIGINT))
FROM [BD_Teste2].[dbo].[Users]
WHERE Extensão <>''
  AND ISNUMERIC([Extensão]) = 1
)

But that does not only occur in 3 results in all 166 rows but

Comment: Done.. IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[cod_extensao]')
AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[cod_extensao];
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cod_extensao] ( [extensao] [varchar](50) NULL,
[codifica_extensao] [varbinary](128) NULL );

Insert into [cod_extensao]
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(Extensão,3) AS BIGINT) as Extensão,CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), CAST(RIGHT(Extensão,3) AS BIGINT)) 
FROM [BD_Teste2].[dbo].[Users] WHERE ISNUMERIC(right(Extensão, 3)) = 1

Comment: @JavaLL, Where is the difference from above post?

Comment: With this query all records were converted.